# LLVM IR How to pass struct to function

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm making my own c-like language and I'm trying to pass a struct to a function. The struct
is representing an array(one member is a pointer to the array and the other member is the length).  If I call the function "test" like this:  `call void @test(%structintarray %a)`   I get error: `'%a' defined with type '%structintarray*' but expected '%structintarray = type { i32*, i32 }' .` But if I call "test" like this: `call void @test(%structintarray* %a)` I get error: `'@test' defined with type 'void (%structintarray)*' but expected 'void (%structintarray*)*'` I don't understand this second error.

What I'm I doing wrong here?
`

```
void test(int[] a) {

}

int main() {
   int[] a = new int[5];
   test(a);
   return 0;
}
```

generates;

```
%structintarray = type { i32*, i32   } 

define void @test(%structintarray %__p__a) {
entry:  %a = alloca %structintarray, align 4
           store %structintarray %__p__a , %structintarray* %a, align 4

           ret void
}


define i32 @main() {
entry:  %t0 = call noalias i8* @calloc(i32 5 , i32 4)
           %t1 = bitcast i8* %t0 to i32*

           %a = alloca %structintarray, align 4
           %t2 = getelementptr %structintarray, %structintarray* %a, i32 0, i32 0
           store i32* %t1 , i32** %t2, align 4     ; pointer to array
           %t3 = getelementptr %structintarray, %structintarray* %a, i32 0, i32 1
           store i32 5 , i32* %t3, align 4         ; size of array

           call void @test(%structintarray %a)
           ret i32 0
}
```

Comment: `alloca` returns a pointer, you'll need to dereference (`load`) it if you want to pass it to a function that takes a struct by value.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks.